# Haskell - String Compression

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to write a function that compresses a string to the characters + number of consecutive occurances of that character such as:
aaaabccc   -> a4bc3

so far I got something like:

```
comp :: String -> Int -> String
comp [] n =[]

comp (x:x1:xs) ct = if(x==x1) then comp (x1:ct:xs) (ct+1) else if(ct>0) then comp (x1:xs) (0) else comp (x1:xs) (0)
comp (x:xs) n = x:xs



main = do
        a <- getLine
        putStrLn $ comp a 0
```

but I get the following error

```
main.cpp:4:45:
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `ct'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `ct : xs'
    In the first argument of `comp', namely `(x1 : ct : xs)'
```

Comment: You are aware that your last `if` is absolutely redundant right?

Comment: You cannot do `x1:ct:xs`, `ct` has type `Int` but `x1` is a `Char` and `xs` is a `[Char]`.  You want to do `x1:show ct ++ xs` or something similar.

Comment: By the way. You could simply use `Data.List.group` and write something like `comp xs = concatMap (\ys -> head ys : show (length ys)) $ group xs`  (not tested)

Comment: Unrelated, minor style comment: try using guards instead of a long chain of `if`s.

Comment: Unrelated: if you ever want to decompress the `String` you should switch to a `[(Char,Int)]` - how would you decompress "aaaa4444" - I guess "a..444times..a"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to append an `Int` to a `String`; you need to explicitely convert it to a `String`first; change:

```
comp (x1:ct:xs)
```

to

```
comp (x1 : show ct ++ xs)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.